# Smart Tags appear for all controls on form but not the actual form itself (VS 2010)

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, smart-tags

Smart Tags appear for all controls on my form, but not the actual form itself.

Looking at this link (Walkthrough: Adding Smart Tags to a Windows Forms Component)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171829.aspx

It seems overly cumbersome to have to modify code for something that is surely just a setting somewhere?  Have I missed something?

I haven't put code against any of my controls on the form (listbox, combobox etc.) and they display the Smart Tags and Action Lists from the little arrows perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by adding the 'Form Assistant' component to my project.